# How to update or modify magento attribute configuration

Tags: magento, attributes, entity, magento-1.7, product

I need to update/modify some `attributes'`  configuration programmatically in Magento (like: `Special Price, Cost, Manufacturer's Suggested Retail Price (that is msrp)`).

I need to set `"Scope" to  "Store View"` to the above fields/attributes/whatever-it-is-called.

How can I achieve this? Please guide me from beginning, with creating an extension, creating class etc.

Thanks.

Comment: Hey, Can you be specific on what you like to perform or like to do so that we can help on that accordingly.

Comment: The thing is, I need an extension/module or whatever it is, to update the "attribute settings/config". Like, I want to change the "Scope" of some attributes. Hope, you got it. :)

Comment: The thing is that I got what you require but you need to mention things specifically here. You require an attribute manager or some list all your all requirements so that I can be more helpful.

Comment: Well, I need to edit/update the `Scope` of the `Special Price, Cost, Manufacturer's Suggested Retail Price (that is msrp)` attributes, to Store View or Website or Global, programaticaly. And this should be done with an `extension/module` or something like that.

Comment: @Chiragit007 I need this [http://www.atwix.com/magento/add-category-attribute/](http://www.atwix.com/magento/add-category-attribute/) kind of explanation, but for `edit/update` case.

Comment: @Chiragit007, I think it's `"entity update"` not `"attribute update"`.